# comparing strings servlet response

Tags: java, string, servlets

A have simple java class to test my servlet. It send json and receives xml, I compare them and always get  not equal, but they shoud be equal. What could be the problem? Servlet send UTF-8.  and string looks the same but are not the same.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException,
        HttpException {
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8080/converter/cs");
    String expected = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><sample><color type=\"string\">red</color></sample>";
    try {
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("json",
                "{\"color\": \"red\"}"));

        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                response.getEntity().getContent()));
        String line = "";
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            s.append(line);
        }
        System.out.println(s.length());
        System.out.println(expected.length());
        System.out.println(s.toString());
        if (s.equals(expected)) {
            System.out.println("equal");
        } else
            System.out.println("not equal");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense to just go over the actual characters and see where you're making incorrect assumptions?!

Comment: if (s.toString().equals(expected)). So first construct string from stringbuffer. adding toString() helped.  Sory for such stupid question, haven't sleep normal for about 2 weeks, trying to get a job.

Comment: @user1255246 - you should post the answer to this question

Answer (score 2):

As the OP mentioned in the comments - the problem is with comparing different types of objects.
In the code the objects are defined as follows:

```
String expected = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><sample><color type=\"string\">red</color></sample>";
...
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    ...
       s.append(...);
    ...
    if (s.equals(expected)) {... // The problem is here, s and expected are not of the same class
```

Replacing the condition with:

```
    if (s.toString().equals(expected)) {...
```

Will resolve the problem.